# Create query string without encoding

Tags: python-3.x, urllib, urlencode

I want to create a query string but without encoding the special character like `@`, `!` or `?`.

Here's my code:

```
payload = {"key": "value", "key2": "value2",
           "email": "test@hello3.ch", "password": "myPassword54321!?"}
print(urllib.parse.urlencode(payload))
```

Now I get as output this:

> password=myPassword54321%21%3F&email=test%40hello3.ch

How can I make my output look like this:

> password=myPassword54321!?&email=test@hello3.ch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`urllib.parse.unquote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote) will replace the `%xx` character escapes with the characters they represent

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode, unquote

print(unquote(urlencode(payload)))
# key=value&key2=value2&email=test@hello3.ch&password=myPassword54321!?
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use the encoding features of `urlencode`, you may as well not use it, since it doesn't do that much else. If you just want to print the key-value pairs seperated by the `&` symbol, and each joined by an `=`, that is straightforward using `str.join` and `str.format`:

```
print("&".join("{}={}".format(key, value) for key, value in payload.items()))
```